# How to access item URL's or _view template in TbGridView

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Yii newbie...

How to access  _view template in TbGridView,
With a CListView, I can do it with:

```
'itemView' => '_view'
```

But itemView is not an option with GridView

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

)); ?>
```

Comment: There is a difference between a `gridView` and a `listView`. A `gridView` displays a table. A `listView` displays a list of items with using `itemView` to render the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply not possible, you should use [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView), or extends [`CGridView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView).

> Unlike [`CGridView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) which displays the data items in a table, [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)
>   allows one to use a view template to render each data item. As a
>   result, [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) could generate more flexible rendering result.

Comment: interested how would you do it with extends CGridView